# Excel Data Insert in particular range cells between A5:Q40

Tags: excel

i create a form using data input datas are stored in another sheets. data are stored in one by one row. i need data are stored in particular cell range. in the below programme datas are inserted the last row. in between empty rows are there. how can i correct it.

```vb
With depname
    
'crow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
next_row = Sheets(depname).Range("A5" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
MsgBox crow
      
        'Sheets(depname).Range("A5").Value = da
        Sheets(depname).Cells(next_row, 1).Value = da
        'Sheets(depname).Range("B5").Value = appno
        'Sheets(depname).Range("C5").Value = depno1
        'Sheets(depname).Range("D5").Value = depno2
        'Sheets(depname).Range("E5").Value = nam
        'Sheets(depname).Range("I5").Value = gen
        'Sheets(depname).Range("J5").Value = rel
        'Sheets(depname).Range("K5").Value = comm
        'Sheets(depname).Range("L5").Value = cas
        'Sheets(depname).Range("O5").Value = dal

        
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 2).Value = Range("last_name").Value
                    
    
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution/code could be like this if I understand you right:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim da As String, appno As String, depname As String
da = "hi"
appno = "hello"
depname = "Sheet1"
i = 1
If da <> "" Then
  Sheets(depname).Cells(5, i) = da
  i = i + 1
End If
If appno <> "" Then
  Sheets(depname).Cells(5, i) = appno
  i = i + 1
End If
End Sub
```

One if state for each variable. You could probably do it much cleaner with a array containing all variable and loop throu all of them like `array = "da, appno, depno1, depno2...."`, but above code works and is simple.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply.  error comes. value only check in range.

Comment: Hi SL Tech, I don't know why it don't work for you. If I add content for the variables (for da, appno and depname), it works like a sharm. Then it's something wrong in your other code. I updated my code if you wanna try it. If you want more help, I need to see more code and what error you get and where the error occur.